# How do you return from a block in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

How do you return from a block in Objective C?

For example, how would you quite early in the following example?

```
[myObject loadThenCallback: ^(id response) {
    if(!response) { 
      // quit early
    }
    // handle response
}];
```

Comment: Think of a obj-c block as a nameless function... so using `return` is good/okay.

Comment: I think it's ok once and a while with really difficult stuff, but I am not a fan of users who repeatedly ask questions they already know the answers to, and then give themselves the rep. A practice you seem to do a lot looking at your history.

Comment: @JustinMeiners: an earlier version of the faq stated, that "jeopardy style question" are ok, as it is still up to other users to provide reputation (note, that in no case someone can provide himself wit reputation)

Comment: @JustinMeiners: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Thanks, Justin. I usually leave SA question with both Q and A when I search Google for something and find answers in a forum, but not SA. Is it better practice to leave easier questions off of SA? Thanks

Comment: @vikingosegundo yes I get that SO says it's ok - but there is a difference between documenting something, and posting a well known answer for up votes. I get that it's technically ok - but I don't like it and I think it devalues the rep system when used repeatedly.

Comment: @JustinMeiners; what defines "well-known"? that it is a document language feature? than SO would be obsolete in any case. That it was answered before? than why did u provide an answer instead of marking the question as duplicate?

Comment: @bbrame I think the difference is - are people dying to know the answer to this one?

Comment: @vikingosegundo it's not even worth googling, one could find the answer in their own code in less time. Thats the difference.

Comment: @JustinMeiners: and you are the authority to decide, if this is an to-die-for answer?

Comment: @JustinMeiners I searched google for it - I was pretty sure, but thought I'd check on SA first. Thought it was good to leave a breadcrumb for the next person with the same question.

Comment: @vikingosegundo you don't have to agree with me. Im just saying I don't like the practice.

Comment: @JustinMeiners — my opinion: if you dont value the question, you should also not answer it. Vote for closure or simply walk away. but dont complain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your solution is okay (other people dont like numerous or early return statements), but of course in this case you just could do

```
[myObject loadThenCallback: ^(id response) {
    if(response) { 
      // handle response
    }
}];
```

---

if I write conditional early return statement, I prefer this code:

```
[myObject loadThenCallback: ^(id response) {
    if(!response) return;

    // handle response
}];
```

it is the same, but I like its brevity.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the return statement in a block to return early.

```
[myObject loadThenCallback: ^(id response) {
    if(!response) { 
      return;
    }
    // handle response
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

[Objective-C blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH7-SW1) are more or less like nameless functions.  There is normally, like functions, a `return` at the end.  See Apple's documentation on code blocks.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of block as an anonymous C function with a little extra built in context data. Everything you expect to do in a function, you can do in a block.

In the same way that `return` works in a C function, `return` works in a block as well.

```
[myObject loadThenCallback: ^(id response) {
    if(someCondition) 
    { 
       return;
    }
}];
```

Make sure to return a type if the block expects it.

```
[myObject callback: ^id(id response) {
    if(someCondition) 
    { 
       return NULL;
    }
    return something;
}]
```